# fix34 codingbat java —why wouldn't this work?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

> Return an array that contains exactly the same numbers as the given array, but rearranged so that every 3 is immediately followed by a 4. Do not move the 3's, but every other number may move. The array contains the same number of 3's and 4's, every 3 has a number after it that is not a 3, and a 3 appears in the array before any 4. Here is the [link](https://codingbat.com/prob/p159339)
>   .

Below is my code.

```
public int[] fix34(int[] nums) {
  for(int k = 0; k<nums.length; k++)
  {
    if(nums[k] == 3)
    {
      int jay = nums[k+1];
      for(int j = 0; j<nums.length; j++)
      {
        if(nums[j] == 4)
        {
          nums[k+1] = nums[j];
          nums[j] = jay;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return nums;
```

I wanted to make it so that if we find the number 3, we go on to look for a 4 (which may be coming before or after 3), and switch the 4 with the number immediately behind 3. However, since it doesn't work for all cases, I'm guessing my code doesn't exactly do that. Or else, is it a logical error? Any help would really be appreciated! (I know there are some other solutions to this out there, but I want to understand what's wrong with mine, exactly.)

Comment: For cases like theses where you cannot figure out what is wrong with your code just by looking at it, it is extremely helpful to step through your program using a debugger. Any mainstream IDEs support this. Debugger allows you to stop the flow of your program at any given point and examine the state of all visible variables in that scope.

Answer (score 1):

I keep your logic and make some changes.  
The inner loop needs a `break` after the 4 is found and the swap is made. 
Also while looking for a 4, bypass any 4s that are after a 3:

```
public static int[] fix34(int[] nums) {
    for(int k = 0; k < nums.length; k++) {
        if(nums[k] == 3) {
            int jay = nums[k+1];
            if (jay != 4) {
                for (int j = 1; j < nums.length; j++) {
                    if (nums[j] == 4 && nums[j - 1] != 3) {
                        nums[k + 1] = 4;
                        nums[j] = jay;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return nums;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array1 = {1, 3, 1, 4};
    int[] array2 = {1, 3, 1, 4, 4, 3, 1};
    int[] array3 = {3, 2, 2, 4};

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array1) + "-->" + Arrays.toString(fix34(array1)));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array2) + "-->" + Arrays.toString(fix34(array2)));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array3) + "-->" + Arrays.toString(fix34(array3)));
}
```

will print

```
[1, 3, 1, 4]-->[1, 3, 4, 1]
[1, 3, 1, 4, 4, 3, 1]-->[1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 3, 4]
[3, 2, 2, 4]-->[3, 4, 2, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You restart `j` at `0` each time you find a `3`. Instead, you need to keep track of where the last `4` you handles was, and start looking for the next one after it:

```
public int[] fix34(int[] nums) {
    int last4 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if (nums[i] == 3) {
            while (nums[last4] != 4) {
                ++last4;
            }
            nums[last4] = nums[i + 1];
            nums[i + 1] = 4;
            ++last4;
        }
    }
    return nums;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a logical error in your code. Every time you check if nums[k] == 3, you run the inner loop which swaps the element right after the 3 with the **first** 4 that it finds in the array. If I illustrate it (albeit very poorly):

We just continue through the loop if nums[k] != 3 since it doesn't do anything.

Your example array = {1,3,2,5,3,4,4}

when k == 1, then nums[k] == 3 is true.

So it runs the inner loop and the array changes to this:

It swaps the 2 at index 2 and 4 at index 5 since the first element 4 is found at index 5

Array after first execution of inner loop: {1,3,4,5,3,2,4}

Then it doesn't do anything until it gets to k == 4

when it gets to k == 4 then nums[k] == 3 is true

So it runs the inner loop and the array changes to this:

Resulting array after second execution of inner loop: {1,3,2,5,3,4,4}

As you can see, it swapped the first 4 (at index 2) with the 2 at index 5. But the first 4 was already placed correctly (by the first execution of inner loop) and should not move. So you need to keep track of the last element that is 4 that you have placed correctly and set the start of your inner loop to be after that last element. Let me know if this makes sense.

Right now as it stands, your program is doing this: find the first element that is 4 and place it after the last element that is 3 (and some elements in the middle is swapped).

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in one while loop also , cheers !

```
public int[] fix34(int[] nums) {

  int start = 0;
  int end = nums.length-1;

  boolean is3 = false;
  boolean is4 = false;


  while( start < nums.length-1 ){

    if(nums[start] == 3){
      is3 = true;
    }

    if(nums[end] == 4){
      is4 = true;
    }


    if(is3 && is4){
      int temp = nums[start+1];
      nums[start+1] = nums[end];
      nums[end] = temp;

      is3 = false;
      is4 = false;
    }



    if(is3){
      end--;
      continue;
    }

    start++;
  }
  return nums;

}
```